# Transforming data in AWS Kinesis Firehose with AWS Lambda / CloudFormation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I found [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-kinesis-firehose-data-transformation-with-aws-lambda/) on the AWS blog that illustrates an example of what I am trying to accomplish. I currently have a workflow that looks like Kinesis Stream --> Kinesis Firehose --> S3 bucket, and I want to introduce a Lambda where I can transform the data before it reaches the final destination.

First, the links for the Lambda blueprints don't work on that article. Nor the official [documentation for the data transformation in Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html#lambda-blueprints). Does anyone have a working Python blueprint for this case?

Secondly, the guide shows that when creating a Firehose Delivery Stream in the AWS Console, there is an option to "Enable" data transformation in Lambda. However, I do not see any property for AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream in the [CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream.html) that would accomplish the same thing. How would I enable this in my CloudFormation template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the CF issue, you're after the [ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-extendeds3destinationconfiguration.html) and more specifically the [ProcessingConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-processingconfiguration.html)

Here's a simple [python processor](https://davidhayden.org/articles/amazon-kinesis-firehose-analytics-s3/)

Comment: ProcessingConfiguration in ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration  cannnot be included under RedshiftDestinationConfiguration.

Comment: Well, yes, configuring S3 when you've indicated Redshift would make no sense.